# How to properly find a conditionally rendered element from onRendered callback?

Tags: meteor, meteor-blaze

I’d like to find a conditionally rendered element after the template is rendered.

The template:

```html
<template name="one">
    <div class="normal">Normal</div>
    {{#if active}}
        <div class="conditional">Conditional</div>
    {{/if}}
</template>
```

The code:

```js
Template.one.onRendered(function() {
    console.log(this.find(".normal"));
    console.log(this.find(".conditional");
}
```

The above will log the ‘.normal’ but null for the ‘.conditional’ (the condition is true, both elements are present in the final DOM). The reason for that is well documented: `onRender` runs before `{{#if}}`s. But I want to run after *the whole* template is rendered, with all its `{{#if}}`s.

Is there a way to find that .conditional without making it a separate template?

Comment: Could you provide a bit of context and explain why you need this element? There may be a simple way to use it, for example in a helper or in events.

Comment: I want to call a function with the element as an argument once it’s rendered, like `boringOldFunction(document.querySelector(".conditional"))`. But the template’s `onRender` runs *before* its `{{#if}}`s are evaluated, so the element doesn’t exist yet. If I make it a separate template instead of `{{#if}}`, I can use its own `onRender` (which would run at the right time), but I thought maybe there is a way to avoid multiple templates here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm facing the same issue. This is because what's inside the {{#if}} block is rendered as a dynamically generated template.

So, the best workaround I've found so far is to render a specific template inside the {{#if}} block and add a callback to this specific template:

Here's what you should do:

```
<template name="one">
    <div class="normal">Normal</div>
    {{#if active}}
        {{> activeTemplate}}
    {{/if}}
</template>

<template name="activeTemplate">
    <div class="conditional">Conditional</div>
</template>

Template.activeTemplate.onRendered(function() {
    console.log(this.find(".conditional");
}
```

Comment: Yes, that’s what I meant by ‘making it a separate template’. That is a valid solution for simpler cases, but in a large scale app, adding one more template purely as a technical workaround is not a solid engineering decision. Apparently, this is the only way of doing it in Meteor, like it or not. This doesn’t strictly answer the question, but it is nevertheless the best solution for the problem itself, so I’m accepting it. Thanks.

Comment: I agree, this is far from being a great solution. I suppose that dynamically generated template should trigger "onRendered" first and then, the parent template. We could create an issue on the Meteor Git page.

Answer (score 0):

You won't find the DOM element because it doesn't exist.

It doesn't exist because `active` is `false`.

If you want `active` to return `true`:

```
Template.one.helpers({
  "active": function() { return true; }
})
```

Comment: I noted that `active` was `true` (it’s a data field), and the element was actually rendered. In short, it does exist, but *after* I have a chance to use it in `onRender`.